# openMP use critical section without brackets

Tags: openmp, critical-section

My question is simple : if I don't use any brackets, does the `#pragma omp critical` apply only to the following line ?

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(k)
for(int i = 0 ; i < bdd.size() ; i++){
#pragma omp critical
    ++k;
    myfunction();
}
```

In the example above is `++k;` the only line affected by the critical section ?

Comment: Yes, and it's better to use `#pragma omp atomic` in that particular case.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this command. After reading the doc, I can't understand what would be the difference with `critical` in that case. Could you clear that for me ?

Comment: `atomic` is in a sense a light-weight version of `critical`. While the latter applies to a block of code, the former can only be applied to a small set of statements like increments, capture and update, and so on.